# Bypassing the AJAX Same-Origin Policy - A particular case

Tags: php, ajax, same-origin-policy

While I was trying to refresh page contents dynamically using Ajax/JQuery, I have learned about the S-O-P issue and restrictions, however I was wondering if there could be a way to solve my little problem.

To make it easier to understand I will first explain the workflow.

I do receive web pages via email, that is HTML emails. The web pages contain HTML forms in such a way, once the form is complete it is sent to the proper web server (php) to store data.

I mostly use Outlook 2007 as my email client (don't say anything here, I know!!!), but for some security restrictions, IFRAMES are disabled when "opening" the email. I have circumvented this problem using a VBA script that copies the whole page content, saves it on the filesystem as a stand-alone web page and loads into the browser (Firefox).

Once the page is loaded into the browser, the address bar shows a local/filesystem URL, such as

```
file:///C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/outlookpage.htm
```

Till here no problem, works fine; now the problem:

I wished to dynamic update page contents using Ajax, using `jQuery.load`, however that's where the S-O-P comes in. The PHP page being loaded to dynamically update the web page is seen as running on another domain, thus being blocked.

I was wondering how to circumvent this.

Comment: I've dealt with SOP in Chrome and IE while working locally. My advice, stick with Firefox and Safari to test if your AJAX works, when you leave you development server it'll work in Chrome and IE, along with the other browsers.

Comment: I'm already using Firefox locally, testing the external script on a local webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work because in order to bypass the same origin policy, you would need to use a proxy on the same domain, which will then communicate to the page that's handling the data on a different domain.  There's no way to generate a proxy script on another user's computer (or at least, there SHOULDN'T BE A WAY).  I would either just post the form normally, which will open the user's default browser, or provide a link to an online form in the email.  The link should be provided anyway, in case their email client doesn't support HTML email.

Comment: Brian, I see your point here. BTW do you think the technique described here (http://www.mikazo.com/2010/09/how-to-getting-around-ajax-same-origin.html) for example it wouldn't work at all?

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me. Probably the best choice is to use an online form. The emailed form contains a link to the online version. Works perfectly. Thanks