# AJAX: overcome same origin policy

Tags: ajax

How do we overcome same origin policy while implementing AJAX?

Comment: Why do you think you need to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is accomplished by implementing [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) script generation on the server, so that generated script calls your callback after it is loaded and executed.

Basically what you need to do is to add script element (with `src` set to your source url). The `script` served should, execute a function call to your supplied callback (sent via URL parameter).

Some Ajax frameworks support this kind of communication out of the box, e.g. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also some publicly available services, support JSONP Ajax communication, e.g. [Twitter](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html) (via `callback` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to AJAX a dynamic page on your site which makes some sort of XMLHTTP request to an external site.  This will fetch the external page from the servers point of view though, not the users.

You shouldn't ever be able to access external pages/sites from clients point of view with native scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For bypassing same origin policy, you should create a proxy and then send the request through proxy...

See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491506/bypassing-the-ajax-same-origin-policy-a-particular-case)

Click here for [Script for proxy setting](http://docs.joomla.org/Avoiding_web_browser_same_origin_policy_in_Ajax_applications)

Additional note, I think firefox 3.5 and more automatically bypasses the same origin policy for ajax..

Answer (score 0):

One option - if the server you want to access provides it - is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to overcome this issue. As said above, the most easy way is to use JSONP in your code.

Another way is to use something called CORS Proxy Alternatives. You can click [here](http://CORS%20Proxy%20Alternatives) to learn more.

You could even use AJAX along with YQL or jQuery. You can click [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/) to see how to do that

Hopefully, that helps!